# Case statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

I have a database table called '**tbl_transaction**' with the following definition:

```
id INT(11) Primary Key
action_type ENUM('Expense', 'Income')
action_heading VARCHAR (255)
action_amount FLOAT
```

I would like to generate two columns: `Income Amt` and `Expense Amt`.

Is it possible to populate the columns conditionally, using only a SQL Query, such that the output appears in the correct column, depending on whether it is an Expense item or an Income item?

For example:

```
ID        Heading         Income Amt       Expense Amt
1         ABC             1000             -
2         XYZ             -                2000
```

I'm using MySQL as the database. I'm trying to use the CASE statement to accomplish this.

Cheers!

Comment: @Pradip: "I'm trying to use CASE statement." Where is that ? Post that too.

Comment: SELECT *, CASE WHEN action_type = 'Expense' THEN 'expense_amount'
ELSE 'income_amount' END
FROM tbl_extra_income_expense

Comment: I'm just getting expense_amount or income_amount string not value.

Comment: Take out the quotes and you'll get values instead of strings.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Yes, something like this:

```
SELECT
    id,
    action_heading,
    CASE
        WHEN action_type = 'Income' THEN action_amount
        ELSE NULL
    END AS income_amt,
    CASE
        WHEN action_type = 'Expense' THEN action_amount
        ELSE NULL
    END AS expense_amt

FROM tbl_transaction;
```

---

As other answers have pointed out, MySQL also has the `IF()` function to do this using less verbose syntax.  I generally try to avoid this because it is a MySQL-specific extension to SQL that isn't generally supported elsewhere.  `CASE` is standard SQL and is much more portable across different database engines, and I prefer to write portable queries as much as possible, only using engine-specific extensions when the portable alternative is *considerably* slower or less convenient.

Answer (score 23):

MySQL also has `IF()`:

```
SELECT 
  id, action_heading, 
      IF(action_type='Income',action_amount,0) income, 
      IF(action_type='Expense', action_amount, 0) expense
FROM tbl_transaction
```

Answer (score 10):

Try to use `IF(condition, value1, value2)`

```
SELECT ID, HEADING, 
IF(action_type='Income',action_amount,0) as Income,
IF(action_type='Expense',action_amount,0) as Expense
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
select 
  id
  ,action_heading
  ,case when action_type='Income' then action_amount else 0 end
  ,case when action_type='Expense' then expense_amount else 0 end
from tbl_transaction
```

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to keep in mind is there are two different CASEs with MySQL: one like what @cdhowie and others describe here (and documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) and something which is called a CASE, but has completely different syntax and completely different function, documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Invariably, I first use one when I want the other.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this would provide you with the right solution:

Syntax:

```
   CASE  
        WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list  
       [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list]....
       [ELSE statement_list]  
   END CASE
```

Implementation:

```
select id, action_heading,  
   case when
             action_type="Expense" then action_amount  
             else NULL   
             end as Expense_amt,   
    case when  
             action_type ="Income" then action_amount  
             else NULL  
             end as Income_amt  
  from tbl_transaction;
```

Here I am using `CASE` statement as it is more flexible than `if-then-else`. It allows more than one branch. And `CASE` statement is standard SQL and works in most databases.