# SQL Select from 4 tables on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables. I will write only important columns.

```
Users (u)    - id
Friends (f)  - sender_id, receiver_id
Fans (fan)   - sender_id (it is me), receiver_id
Activity (a) - sender_id, receiver_id
```

I need to get activities from my friends and from people whom I support.

It means that there are these possibilities:

```
1) u.id = f.sender_id   AND f.receiver_id   = a.sender_id
2) u.id = f.sender_id   AND f.receiver_id   = a.receiver_id
3) u.id = f.receiver_id AND f.sender_id     = a.sender_id
4) u.id = f.receiver_id AND f.sender_id     = a.receiver_id
5) u.id = fan.sender_id AND fan.receiver_id = a.sender_id
6) u.id = fan.sender_id AND fan.receiver_id = a.receiver_id
```

Is there any other solution than using UNION?
The database structure cannot be changed it is from bought extension.

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you want to use UNION?

Comment: @Explosion Pills How?

Comment: @OblTobl I was curious if there is another solution and I have been told that union is not so good solution. I am not so experinced in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can use case statement. To make sure, please post your query using UNION then I'll convert it for you to case statement.

Or you can use the link below as a reference:
[Case statement in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265874/case-statement-in-mysql)

Comment: by the way, UNION is the best approach. It has a good performance and it's a code easy to read.

Comment: So I don't even need to convert it? If so I will write it just as  UNION.