# Case statement for a date field with Mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql

Iam trying to do a CASE statement. The requirement is if Date field is NULL then show it as 'Pending' or else show the date from the db.

I have tried the below case statement but there is some problem.

```
CASE po_amend_received_date IS NULL WHEN 1 THEN 'Pending'  
ELSE po_amend_received_date END AS `po_amend_received_date`
```

Am i making any mistake here?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265874/case-statement-in-mysql

Comment: what is the use of `WHEN 1` ?

Comment: @ Kim, that's my mistake i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN po_amend_received_date IS NULL THEN 'Pending'  
else  po_amend_received_date 
end as `po_amend_received_date`
```