# SQL IF ELSE STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
1. SELECT ORDER
FROM ORDERLIST
WHERE IsCompleted='Y'

2. SELECT ORDER
FROM ORDERLIST
WHERE IsCompleted='N'
```

**THEN THE OUTPUT IS 'NULL'**

I would like to integrate this two logic, but I don't know how to make the code work. Please help me!

Comment: don't name your table `order`

Comment: take a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265874/case-statement-in-mysql

Comment: `order` should be placed inside backticks \`order\` or better just avoid using reserved keywords.

Comment: @Fabre No need to shout, even if it's an SQL question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

You can use `CASE WHEN` Expression

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN IsCompleted='Y' 
        THEN
            [ORDER]
        ELSE WHEN IsCompleted='N' 
        THEN
           NULL
    END 
FROM 
    ORDERLIST
```

Comment: Case expression, not statement.

Comment: Much better! (A case expression returns a value. A case statement is just conditional execution of code, for example in a stored procedure.)

Answer (score 0):

'Intergrate' as in `UNION`?:

```
SELECT ORDER
FROM ORDERLIST
WHERE IsCompleted='Y'
UNION
SELECT NULL
FROM ORDERLIST
WHERE IsCompleted='N'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, this should allow you to get all the results in one table.

```
    SELECT ORDER
    FROM ORDERLIST
    WHERE IsCompleted = 'Y' OR IsCompleted = 'N'
```