# How to use the CTE to get recursive record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I am writing this query:

```
with CTE as
(
SELECT testCategory, testType, compareTestCategory,A.MEDIAN, A.average from 
tInputValue_SamplesRequired

)

Select testCategory,testType,C.Median,C.Average,C.Median + D.Median as change,C.Average + D.average as [%change],C.compareTestCat from CTE C
left outer CTE D
on C.testCategory = D.compareTestCategory
and C.testType = D.testType
```

I would like to get the recursive record such as below image :
[image]

However I the result I got is like below :
[image]

By right, if the compare test category is equal to test category, I would like to use the median and average to the calculation.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Alex Microsoft sql server

Comment: Can you post some DDL and Sample Data please? A SQL query on it's own means little if we don't have any objects or data to use it with.

Comment: What is the intended meaning of compare_tTest_Cateogory_id. Your results look identical except for ordering and that column which is not defined in your select statement

Comment: @steveb sorry, I don't need the compare_tTest_Category_id. I just want to compare the OP from compareTestCategory and OP from testCategory

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal, so you want to have a different output in %change if compareTestCategory is equal to testCategory? Have you tried a case statement? You can find an example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265874/case-statement-in-mysql

Comment: hi @steveb I didn't try it yet.

Comment: @MuhammadAkmal, so you want the %change column?   What calculation do you want to use when test category = test category?